# How can I disable the css {position:fixed} side-bar on Slashdot?

Tags: greasemonkey, website

When I look at a story on Slashdot, I see a side-bar that sits constantly in the upper-left corner. Every time I open a story, I have to click on the "slash" sign in its upper-right corner.

[image]

How can I disable it, so it will always have css position absolute, relative or static? Is there an option for it? Because I find it is slowing my browser down when I am scrolling the page.

I am a registered Slashdot user, logged in.

Comment: I'm sure I'm being dumb, but I can't recreate - could you post a link?

Comment: That is a Screenshot taken from this URL: http://tech.slashdot.org/story/10/06/02/2317241/EU-To-Monitor-All-Internet-Searches The title at the top is the title of my browser's tab. The box below it is always fixed on the page and it is quite annoying.

Comment: can you write greasemonkey scripts?

Comment: @Andy I had hoped to find a configuration setting.

Comment: Understood, don't know if it's possible, not sure how it would be presented if it was. Good luck!

Comment: Cross-referencing similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664285/how-do-i-disable-positionfixed-in-web-pages https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696100/greasemonkey-script-to-make-fixed-positioned-elements-static

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are willing to use the old Slashdot discussion style, you can disable dynamic discussions to remove this.  Follow these steps to disable dynamic discussions:

1. Login
2. Click on [Help & Preferences](http://tech.slashdot.org/help)
3. Under *Discussions* click on *Viewing*
4. Uncheck *Enable Dynamic Discussions*
5. Click *Save*

Comment: This does solve the problem, but it disables the whole JavaScript. I only want that box to be gone when I scroll down.

Comment: @Tom: That is correct. Personally I prefer the old Slashdot comment style but I am used to it because that's how Slashdot has always been in my mind (due to nostalgia). I know of no other way to disable the floating box that follows you down the page via Slashdot's preferences. If you want a solution that specifically solves this problem you will probably have to use a custom browser extension (you'll need to tell us your browser for this).

Answer (score 1):

Install [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (if you haven't already) and [this user script](https://gist.github.com/vbuaraujo/bddb3b93a0b2b7e28e1b). This appears to disable `position: fixed` everywhere; if for some bizzare reason that is a problem for you, edit the @include line to taste. You may need to add `,null` to the `window.getComputedStyle` call or `,false` to the `window.addEventListener` call (or other adjustments); if so, you probably won't get get any notification that you need to do so, just the script silently failing.